# Explain this statement $\bar 0 \in \partial f(x^*)$ where $\partial f(x^*)$ is subgradient

Tags: optimization

I haven't understood this theorem *"$x^*$ is global minimum iff $\bar 0\in \partial f(x^*)$"*. What does it mean? Visually?

[image]

*P.s. Studying Nonlinear-optimization -course, 2.3139.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is a convex function, to say that $g \in \partial f(x)$ means that
\begin{equation*}
f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle g, y - x \rangle
\end{equation*}
for all $y$.

For example, let $f(x) = |x|$.  $f$ is not differentiable at $0$,
but $f$ is convex, and $f$ has a subdifferential $\partial f(0)$.

And you can see that $0 \in \partial f(0)$ in this example.

So... note that if $f$ is convex then
\begin{align*}
& x \text{ is a minimizer of } f \\
\iff & f(y) \geq f(x) \, \forall \, y \\
\iff & f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle 0 , y - x \rangle \, \forall \, y \\
\iff & 0 \in \partial f (x).
\end{align*}

Comment: What does it mean "f has a subdifferential ∂f(0)"? I got $|x|\leq g\cdot x$ which is true when $x=0$. Is my answer correct? I am wondering what I meant when I wrote "subgradient not unique in the picture", thinking. +1 thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that for a convex function $f$, $\partial f(x)$ is equal (by definition) to $\{ g \mid f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle g, y - x \rangle \, \forall \, y\}$.  In the example where $f(x) = |x|$, $\partial f(0)$ contains all real numbers between $-1$ and $1$ (inclusive).

Comment: The reason that $0 \in \partial f(0)$ (when $f(x) = |x|$) is that $|y| \geq |0| + \langle g, y - 0 \rangle$ for all $y$ when $g = 0$.  (Actually this holds for any value of $g$ between $-1$ and $1$.)

Answer (score 0):

I can only understand this in the format:

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a convex function. Suppose its Hessian matrix $\nabla^2 f$ is positively definite i.e. its square-form $x \left(\nabla^2 f \right)x^T$ is positive. Now $x^*$ is global minimum iff $\bar 0\in \partial f(x^*)$".

This is understandable because it would mean that the subgradient has a point in which $\nabla f =0$.

**Video recommendation**

> Very good video in point 18-26.00 in Stanford [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3lJAObbMFI).
>
> [image]

Comment: $f$ may not be differentiable, though.  Even if a convex function $f$ is not differentiable at $x$, $f$ may at least have one or more subgradients at $x$.

Comment: @littleO what does the global-minimum actually mean? What does it look geometrically?