# KKT: Explain visually the optimality condition $F_0\cap G_0\cap H_0=\emptyset$

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to understand visually what this condition actually mean. It is the optimality condition in KKT. It means something like that constraint -set, objective -set and hyperplane -set has no common directions. I have seen only abstract definitions without examples so I have very vague understanding about this statement. Please, explain it, perhaps with some easy examples.

[image]

*P.s. I am doing the non-linear optimization 2.3139.*