# Explain Complementary Slackness $\mu_i g_i(x^*)=0\forall i$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Complementary_slackness) explains it like this:

[image]

I understand it so that either $\mu_i=0$ or $g_i=0$ but this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/220870/5902):

> "If μ1≠0 and μ2≠0, then x is one of the two points at the intersection of the two circles (complementary slackness)"

where I cannot see at all what it has to do with complementary-slackness. Could someone clarify this concept and this example? Please, choose an simpler example if the latter too detailed.

*P.s. I am doing the non-linear optimization 2.3139.*

Answer (score 1):

You may want to see the video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJVmflArCXc&feature=relmfu) and at the very end something about complementary-slackness -condition.

[image]